# Angular Compare 2 arrays by filter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a 2 arrays i need to show only data which match with first array.

Example

first array is like

```
["1", "2" , "3"]
```

second is like

```
[{"name": "xyz", "id": "1"},{"name":"abc", "id": "3"}, ,{"name":"def", "id": "4"}]
```

result

```
[{"name": "xyz", "id": "1"},{"name":"abc", "id": "3"}}
```

I try like this but showing empty Array

```
console.log(this.secondArr.filter(d => d.id === firstArr));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare it with each entry in the array, not the array itself:

```
this.secondArr.filter(d => firstArray.some(arrEntry => arrEntry === d.id))
```